# Angular 6+ how to extend the default configuration (was environment)

Tags: angular

I have multiple Angular configurations.

To extend the default configuration, I use lodash merge:

```js
import { merge } from 'lodash'
import { defaults } from './defaults'

export const configuration = merge(defaults, {
  debugApp: 'sp5:auth,sp5:sim-filter-system'
})
```

However, when I build with the AOT flag this approach is causing problems.

What is the correct approach to extend a configuration? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```js
const config = {
  debugApp: 'sp5:auth,sp5:sim-filter-system'
};

Object.keys(defaults).forEach(key => config[key] = config[key] ? config[key] : defaults[key]);

export const configuration = config;
```

This should get all the keys in `defaults`, and if you declared them in `config`, they will keep their value.

Comment: thanks this helped me although I have added my own answer to fully doc this

Answer (score 0):

It turns out an AOT build seems to only like ES5 syntax in certain places. This was one of them.

```
import { defaults } from './defaults'

export const configuration = Object.assign(defaults, {
  debugApp: 'sp5:auth,sp5:sim-filter-system'
})
```

Also, I read somewhere that on an AOT build, you can use a static function if it only has one statement and that statement is a return statement.